# Python - swda - using the CorpusReader

Tags: python, python-2.7, metadata, package, corpus

I'm trying to use the CorpusReader from the swda package, using a corpus from swda-metadata.csv, which was taken from the internet.  I'm trying to print out the (word, POS) tags from the corpus by using the following method, but it won't show any output.

```
def get_corpus():
    corpus = swda.CorpusReader(...)   #this is where the swda-metadata.csv directory path goes
    get_utterances = corpus.iter_utterances()
    for i in get_utterances:
        print i.pos_lemmas()
```

Comment: It comes from this website: http://compprag.christopherpotts.net/swda.html#r

Answer (score 0):

The "swda-metadata.csv" file that comes in the swda.zip package is just the metadata describing the transcripts; it has no transcripts and thus no utterences to be found.  One needs some transcripts, as from swb1_dialogact_annot.tar.gz on the same site.

Comment: From the website it says:
"When you unpack swda.zip, you get a directory with the same basic structure as that of swb1_dialogact_annot.tar.gz. The file swda-metadata.csv contains the transcript and caller metadata for this subset of the Switchboard."
so I downloaded the zip file and used the swda-metadata.csv as the transcript file

Comment: I think that means that swda-metadata.csv  contains _only_ the metadata (information about) for the transcripts and callers, and _does not_ contain any (non-meta-)data of the transcripts.  You could verify this by simply looking inside swda-metadata.csv with a text editor or Excel.  The data of the transcripts is in wb1_dialogact_annot.tar.gz and would be much larger in size than swda-metadata.csv .